# CTRL + PLUS event on Firefox and Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, firefox

It is possible to catch <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>+</kbd> / <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd> events on Firefox with :

```
window.onkeydown = function(event)
{
  if(event.ctrlKey && event.keyCode == 61)
        CtrlPlus();
  if(event.ctrlKey && event.keyCode == 169) // or == 54, depends on keyboard layout
        CtrlMinus();
};
```

But in Chrome, it doesn't work : <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>+</kbd> is always linked at Chrome's internal "Zoom +" command.

**How is it possible to override Chrome's <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>+</kbd> ?**

Comment: Did you try `event.preventDefault();`? https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/event.preventDefault

Comment: @Prusse it works! (I had tested this before, and I thought it didn't work, I maybe made a mistake...) If you copy/paste as an answer, I'll accept it !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try `event.preventDefault();`?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/event.preventDefault

Comment: now it doesn't work with Safari..... Any idea @Prusse : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26002958/event-preventdefault-works-on-chrome-firefox-but-not-safari?noredirect=1#comment40723240_26002958

Comment: Try to also `return false` like suggested in this other answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/6186102/783219

Comment: It may offer some light reading http://stackoverflow.com/q/1357118/783219, this one is a thread about jquery, but some info may be helpful. You may ALSO try `stopPropagation`.