# event.preventDefault() works on Chrome, Firefox, but not Safari

Tags: javascript, html, safari

This HTML / JS code :

```
<script>
window.onload = function(e) {
window.onkeydown = function(event) {
        if (event.ctrlKey && (event.keyCode == 61 || event.keyCode == 187)) 
        {
          event.preventDefault();
          alert("hello");
          return false;
        }
      }
}
</script>
<p>Blah</p>
```

**overrides** the browser CTRL+PLUS  's  ZOOM keyboard shortcut.

It works on Firefox, Chrome, but not with Safari : with Safari, if you do CTRL+PLUS on this page, the `alert("hello")` is launched, but the browser's zooming is also changed !

This means that `event.preventDefault();` hasn't worked like it should have worked.

**How to use `event.preventDefault()` with Safari ?**

*Note: I already tried as well with StopPropagation, but it doesn't solve the problem.*

Comment: Why wait for the onload? are the keycodes the same in Safari!

Comment: I first did a test without wait for the onload @mplungjan. As it did not work, I tried with waiting for onload... but you're right, finally it doesn't change anything.

Comment: @mplungjan if the keycodes were wrong, then `alert('hello');` wouldn't be called... (but it is called when i do a test)

Comment: Does `event.cancelable()` report that it is cancelable? Maybe this is non-standard behavior for those browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like this is problem with `ctrlKey`. Assuming you use Mac OS X system you need to check for `metaKey` too, so your code should be:

```
if ((event.ctrlKey || event.metaKey) && (event.keyCode == 61 || event.keyCode == 187))
```

Comment: problem solved... I was using Safari for Windows to do my test (as I don't have a Mac), so that explained why the results were strange... moreover Safari/Win seems to be not developed anymore...

Answer (score 1):

We probably have different keyboard layouts or something, but my `+` and `-` signs on my numpad have the key code values 107 and 109. (http://www.asquare.net/javascript/tests/KeyCode.html)

The code snippet below works in safari for me.

```js
window.onkeydown = function (event) {
    if (event.ctrlKey && (event.keyCode == 107 || event.keyCode == 109)) {
        event.preventDefault();
        alert("hello");
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks @Mandera ! When you use CTRL+(Numpad +), does it display 'hello' and does it prevent from zooming ?
What happens when you use CTRL+(+) ? [The `+` key which is near `backspace` http://www.goodtyping.com/teclatUSok.png] Does it prevent from zooming as well?

Comment: Oh there we go, that `+` key which has keyCode 187, produced the same error you're trying to solve... (Alert but didn't prevent zoom) That is very odd.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
window.onkeydown = function(event) {
        if (event.ctrlKey && (event.keyCode == 61 || event.keyCode == 187)) 
        {
          if (event.preventDefault){
             event.preventDefault();
          }
          else {
             event.returnValue = false;
          }
          alert("hello");
          return false;
        }
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The key codes for zoom are different across browsers:

```
Opera   MSIE  Firefox  Safari  Chrome 
 61     187     107     187     187      = +             
109     189     109     189     189      - _
```

Also try :

```
event.stopImmediatePropagation();
```

To prevent other handlers from executing.