# Why is preventDefault() not working on Safari?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, contact-form-7

i'm trying to submit a contactform 7 form on safari but it doesn't work because of event.preventDefault(). In all other browsers it is working, like it should. After submit the api should get a post with serialized data. can't find a solution for this, hope you can help me out on this.

```
<div class="formular">
    <?php echo do_shortcode( '[contact-form-7 id="1234"]' ); ?>
</div>
```

```
$(".formular form").submit(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var formValues = $(this).serialize();    
});
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7mailsent', function( event ) {
    if ( '1234' == event.detail.contactFormId ) {
   var formValues = $('.formular form').serialize();
      $.post("https://api", formValues, function(data){
    });
    }
}, false );
</script>
```

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6185992/preventdefault-in-safari

Comment: thank you, i have already seen this post but return false didn't change anything at all.